# Vector addition and Pythagorean theorem

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, triangles

Finding length or magnitude using vector addition and the Pythagorean theorem.

I am trying to understand why vector addition and the Pythagorean theorem are giving different results?

[image: vector_addition]

**Vector Addition** :

According to diagram (A) :  $\vec{a} + \vec{b} = \vec{c}$

now suppose : magnitude of $\vec{a} = 3$, magnitude of $\vec{b} = 4$ then

$\|\vec{c}\| = \|\vec{a}\| + \|\vec{b}\|$

$\|\vec{c}\| = 3 + 4$

> **magnitude of c = 7**

**Pythagorean Theorem**

Now when we consider this as a triangle shown in diagram (B)

Similarly, length of $a = 3$, length of $b = 4$

so according to Pythagorean theorem

$\text{hypotenuse}^2 = \text{opposite}^2 + \text{adjacent}^2$

$c^2 = a^2 + b^2$

i.e.

$c^2 = 3^2 + 4^2$

$c = \sqrt{9 + 16} = \sqrt{25}$

> **length of c = 5**

Why there is inconsistency in the results? I am doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: In general $\|a\|+\|b\|\neq \|a+b\|$.  What is true however is the "*triangle inequality*" for norms, saying $\|a+b\|\leq \|a\|+\|b\|$.  In terms of euclidean distance, equality only holds if $a$ and $b$ are in the same "direction."

Comment: Letting $a=(3,0)$ and $b=(0,4)$, we have $c=a+b=(3,0)+(0,4)=(3,4)$.  The magnitude of $c$ (with respect to euclidean distance) is $\|(3,4)\|=\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=\sqrt{25}=5$, as expected.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: thank you for updating the question. I will go through the tutorial!

Answer (score 1):

**Vector Magnitude**

The magnitude of a vector $(\vec{a} + \vec{b})$ is obtained in a similar way to that for Pythagorean triangles. It is incorrect to simply add up magnitudes of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

Rather, $\| \vec{c} \| = \sqrt {\| \vec{a} \| + \| \vec{b} \|} $ (See link).

[Khan Academy](https://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/vectors-precalc/adding-vectors-in-magnitude-and-direction-form/v/mag-vec-sums&ved=0ahUKEwjYqOv6yJnMAhWDwxQKHVsuAXUQtwIIGDAA&usg=AFQjCNGVaXjFxMfnVhjyp7l_Igvy-j2XDA&sig2=G4a2KCxIlu97PvS9byEh6Q)

*As @JMoravitz has already demonstrated.*

Comment: As a side note, for magnitude, it is recommended to use `\|a\|` as opposed to `||a||`.  Compare the following:  $\|a\|~~~~~||a||$

Comment: Thank you for the note. I shall adjust.